# Cannot Access props inside function of functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-functional-component

I am trying to use props inside function of functional props.

```
const Inputs = (props) => {
    console.log(props.printFirstArray);
    const FirstInputSet = () => {
        console.log(props.printFirstArray)
   }
}
```

**First** `console.log` is logging the value of `printFirstArray`, but **second** `console.log` inside `FirstInputSet()` function is not logging anything.
Edit: Minimal Code

```
const Inputs = (props) => {
    const FirstInputSet = () => {
        return (
            <>
                <div className="first input-set">
                    {props.printFirstArray}
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }

    const renderFirstInputSet = () => {
        if (props.firstInputValue)
            return <FirstInputSet />
        else
            return null;
    }

return (
    <>
            {renderFirstInputSet()}
    </>
);
}
```

Neither props.printFirstArray nor props.printSecondArray is not returning anything

Comment: How are you calling `FirstInputSet`? (It's a function).

Comment: Doing this anywhere FirstInputSet()? This calls the function

Comment: FirstInputSet is a JSX return function which is bieng called in the main function but nothing is returning.

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve]. Your function isn't returning anything because it's _not_ returning anything.

Comment: The code you are showing -> `FirstInputSet ` is a null OP, your just creating a function that you never run.

Comment: check now, I added the whole code

Comment: What is `printFirstArray`? It sounds like a function, but you're not calling it.

Comment: printFirstArray is a state

Answer (score 0):

From your code, `FirstInputSet` is a new component and you aren't passing any props.

```
return <FirstInputSet />
```

Try to pass your props to the child component but I recommend keeping the child component out of parent component.

OR

If you meant to use `FirstInputSet` as a function, you can modify the code like below

```
return FirstInputSet();
```

Comment: FirstInput is a new component and i am not passing any props because its not returning anything and props are already provided by Inputs component

Comment: Props of FirstInput ≠ Props of Input.
They are two different components.